# Find duplicates in List

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code:

```
List<MyType> myList = new List<MyType>();
// ... add items to the list
var dupes = myList.GroupBy(g => g).Where(x => (x.Count() > 1))
                  .Select(x => new { obj = x.Key, count = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

`dupe` is always empty, even if I intentionally insert duplicates into the list. What should I add to MyType definition to make it work ? I implemented `Equals(object obj)` and `CompareTo(object obj)` for MyType, but none of these methods gets called.

Comment: It would probably be faster to filter (i.e. call `Where`) after `Select`.

Comment: `DefaultEqualityComparer` prefers to use `IEquatable<MyType>.Equals(MyType)` rather than `System.Object.Equals(Object)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you implemented GetHashCode correctly, to match your `Equals` method? It won't be using `CompareTo` (that's for ordering) but *will* use `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

If you believe you've done that already, please post the code for `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: I missed `GetHashCode`. I'm adding it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were right, compiler did actually warn me about it, I should have figured it out by myself...